# Canon Lens Mount on other brands

Tags: canon, compatibility

I have a Canon T2i (2010) I am looking to upgrade. Are there any other brands of camera that my Canon lenses will fit?

Comment: Yes, look at Red cameras, if you like video ;-D

Answer (score 1):

The Canon Rebel T2i uses Canon lenses with an EF lens mount.

You can mount these lenses to a variety of other cameras using an adapter. Here are some examples:

- [Canon EF to Sony NEX](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=994949&gclid=Cj0KEQjwkv-rBRDwoMLav-2l9KIBEiQAUTkDU4r_yxw2Y0HBY3ziAkZO76IlZQrB_pelpVJZXBPrHo4aAkGo8P8HAQ&Q=&is=REG&A=details)
- [Cannon EF to FujiFilm X-Mount](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=1063345&gclid=Cj0KEQjwkv-rBRDwoMLav-2l9KIBEiQAUTkDU5O9KHd76QC1SSjs24LziXKbTWN8xn8QKfXV-NbzackaAih08P8HAQ&Q=&is=REG&A=details)
- [Canon   EF to Canon EOS M](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/983576-REG/vello_lae_cm_cef_auto_lens_adapter_for.html)

Typically you will only see adapters to mount a lens on an equal or lower end camera (not many people will mount a cheap lens on a Hasselblad for example).

Answer (score 0):

No SLRs (Canon has a shorter mount registration distance, a complete deal-breaker)(O.K., maybe 4/3s would work.), but yeah, there are adapters for various mirrorless systems.

But you're usually better off using a lens designed for the system you're using it on. Things like autofocus are likely be absent or impaired on foreign systems.

There are a bunch of good reasons for living with the drawbacks of mixed systems. But if you can't articulate one, don't.